# webkitcore compile failed

Tags: ios, webkit

I compile the webkitCore in Xcode, and set the base SDK to ios6, but an error happen:

```
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.tool', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform
```

how to solve this , thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer:

- Use text editor to open the ***xxx.xcodeproj*** (the blue project icon)
- In project.pbxproj file, search for "***productType***"
- Replace the type with
  "***productType = "com.apple.product-type.library.static";***"

Hope this can help